# How can I use AAD for Company XXX that require to have Active Directory in the cloud 100%

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I how can I use Azure Active Directory for a company xxx whose AD is completely in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Azure already has an Active Directory free tier, depends on what is your needs it can be a good choice. Please have a look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis). You can also change tier to a Premium Azure AD where there are more options.

Another choice is Azure Active Directory Domain Services, more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview)

Both solution are "completely on the cloud". Sometimes you can see a Virtual Machine (IaaS) as a Domain Controller, in this case it works like a on-prime environment on the cloud.